# react native this.props.navigation is undefined in main APP

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use "this.props.navigation" in my main react native App but it is undefined. In my others components included with TabNavigator and ScreenNavigator it work.

My App.js

```
const MyTabView = TabNavigator(
  {     
    Projects: { screen: Projects },     
    Explorer: { screen: Explorer },
    Profil: { screen: Profil }, ... 
  }        
);



const StackView = StackNavigator(
  {
    global: {
      screen: MyTabView,
      headerMode: "none",
      header: null,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },

    TermsOfUse: { screen: TermsOfUse },
    LegalNotice: { screen: LegalNotice },
    Options: { screen: Options }, ...       
  } 
);

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props); 
    console.log(this.props.navigation); // <----------  UNDEFINED
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={<ActivityIndicator />}
          persistor={persistor}>

          <View style={styles.fullScreen}>
            <StackView />

            <Tutorial navigation={this.props.navigation} />  // <----------  this.props.navigation  is  UNDEFINED
          </View>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`navigation` prop is only available on components that are in navigation stack or child components that are using [`withNavigation` HOC](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html).

Comment: how to pass navigation to components who are not in stack/tab navigator ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `App` class is not included in the `Navigator` stack, due to which, the navigator class cannot provide any navigation props to it, that is why you are getting an `undefined` error because the `navigation` object doesn't exist.

Also if you need to open `<Tutorial/>` as a first screen, include it as the first element in the `StackNavigator`. That ways, it'll be always called first.

PS: You can additionally provide `navigation={this.props.navigation}` element to different components, which does not have to be included in the navigator class. For example, you need to open a `dropdown` element, which provides a sign out option that navigates to a home screen. In this use case, it'll be better to provide the `navigation` props as you have provided it in the question. But care needs to be taken, that the class providing the prop should have the object present

**EDIT**

According to your requirement, you need to display a tutorial for each screen that you open. You can do it via two approaches.

1. Your way - You can declare it in the stack navigator. But your `<Tutorial/>` component will contain multiple conditions to check for the route and display the appropriate data ( that's what I can think of right now ).
2. You can declare a common component that only shows the message in a modal. You can then declare an optional prop for each component, and in each of your components, you can check if this optional prop exists, you can show your common display `<Tutorial/>` component.

This is what I can think of currently. Will update if I have more thoughts :)

Hope this answers.

Comment: ok thank you. i use `navigation={this.props.navigation}` on many of my components.  <toturial/> should be a global component, on each road change i want to detect the current road and display a Modal

Comment: yes or the navigation props should be passed to tutorial component by some component having already having navigation props

Comment: Also, why are you using a route to display a modal? You can always toggle its display state and populate the values of the modal with your new values. In my opinion, route should only be changed, if there is a new page to be rendered.

Comment: so i should use <Tutorial navigation={this.props.navigation} /> directly in each components of stack/tab Navigator. i wanted to put it just one "gloabally".

Comment: "why are you using a route to display a modal? " -> 
for example i'm in the first tabnavigator screen, projects, so i display the tutorial for "projects", if user go to "explorer" screen i show the tutorial for this screen and so on

Comment: yes that was the ideas but i didn't found a way to implement them. cannot use redux in `navigationOptions` (static) of each components to change the store on each tab click for example

Comment: i'll just give an example - have a json which maps which tutorial to display on which screen. Once you are on that screen, fetch the tutorial using the screen as a key. Use the tutorial data to display it on the tutorial component

Comment: the problem is : i cannot get the current name road !

Comment: you have to pass the current name of the road as props to the component as well from the component you are rendering road in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174009/discussion-between-alainib-and-aseem-upadhyay).